# Get link of a button and assign to other in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an ecommerce site, I have a page that shows the products grid. There are two button side by side. One contains link to the post and other opens a dialogue box with textarea inside. (see picture)

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Now, what I want is when I click the **GETLINK BUTTON** button it must take the **href** attribute of the **VIEW BUTTON** and populate in the textarea. But what I get in the link of 1st product only even if I click the other Get Link Buttons.

Here's the JS code:

```
function opengetlink(){
    var sacprodlink = document.getElementById("sac_prod_link").href;
    jQuery("#sac_link_text").html(sacprodlink);
}
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Solved**

```
$(".open").click(function() {

    var link = $(this).closest('div.viewbutton').find('a.btn-link').attr('href');

    $("#link_text").html(link);

});
```

Comment: Duplicate ID problem .Show HTML not image.

Comment: You need to use relative elements, eg `$("#sac_open_link").click(function() { $(this).siblings(".sac_prod_link").href; ...`  use classes not IDs as they must be unique in the page.  Can't be more specific without the html.

Comment: You are using the `getElementById()` method that matches the first id you specify (because you are not supposed to have more than one identical id per page).

Comment: First you have to work with classes not id's (semanticly error ) , also when clicking on the get link you'ill use the this keywork and search backwork (prev() find() or parent().find("sac_prod_link") ....) for the button then get it's href

Comment: show some code for better help

Comment: Use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). Get the parent element of the specific **Get link** button and then query for **View** element and read *href* attribute. Check @ https://coderwall.com/p/wxjljq/jquery-find-and-closest-are-your-best-friends

Comment: @thirueswaran thanks for the suggestion. I got the desired result. Please check edit. Thanks others for pointing out the ID Conflict.

Comment: @SikandarAliChishty glad I could help...

Answer (score 0):

Ids are given to HTML elements to make them unique. Since you have many elements of the same kind and want to perform the same operation on each of them, you should use classes. Give your `View` and `Get Link` buttons a class.

```
$(".sac_open_link").click(function() {
    var link = $(this).siblings(".sac_prod_link").href;
    $(this).html(link);
});
```

Comment: I tried that solution but couldn't get the result but I worked with your suggestion of using class instead of ID. Please see the Edit for solution.